# How is the python module search path determined on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, macos, pythonpath, sys.path

When a non built-in module is imported, the interpreter searches in the locations given by `sys.path`. `sys.path` is initialized from these locations (http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path):

1. the directory containing the input script (or the current directory)
2. PYTHONPATH
3. the installation-dependent default

While the first two sources are straight-forward, can anyone explain how the third one works, and what possibilities there are for influencing it?

Although I would be interested in a general solution, my specific issues are:

- I have installed the [Enthought distribution 7.2 32-bit](http://www.enthought.com/), and then [Scipy-Superpack](http://fonnesbeck.github.com/ScipySuperpack/). Now enthought python tries to import numpy from `/Library/Python/2.7/`, which is where superpack installed them, instead of from the enthought site-packages.
- a `wxPython` application created with `py2app` `-A` does not have the same `sys.path` as when starting the application with `python start_app.py`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basis of the third source is set at compile time (or configure time, more precisely), depending on the platform. It is then expanded and added to at run-time via `.pth` files, etc. (which is something you can do once the Python executable is compiled to influence that third source).

This page of the Python documentation has all the information on how `.pth` files work, and also more information on how `sys.path` is constructed from build-time settings, etc. http://docs.python.org/library/site.html

I'm not sure why you want to influence that third source specifically though, when you can influence the whole `sys.path`. Anyhow, the three ways of influencing `sys.path` (without recompiling Python or patching the source code) are:

1. Via the PYTHONPATH environment variable.
2. By creating `.pth` files and dropping them where Python scans for packages. (See the link earlier for details.)
3. Programmatically, by importing `sys` and then appending or prepending to `sys.path`

   ```
   import sys
   sys.path.insert(0, '/this/path/will/be/considered/first')
   ```

Hopefully one of these three ways should help you do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! The reason I am interested in the third source specifically is for cases where there are unwanted libraries that are not in the `PYTHONPATH`, that cause an error where I have no direct access to sys.path, e.g. when building sphinx documentation.

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac OS X 10.7.5 system, I also had the problem that Enthought python was looking for modules in /Library/Python/2.7/. Apparently, this was caused by the file easy-install.pth located in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages. After changing the extension of this file Enthought python imported the Enthought modules (from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages).