# How to import custom python package by name

Tags: python, module, python-3.x, python-module

I have created a folder named "custom_module" and I have the __init__.py inside the folder which contains:

```
__all__ = [
        'Submodule1',
        'Submodule2'
]
```

From what documentation I read I should be able to call `import custom_module` and get access to the package, however this isn't happening. How can I make python recognize my package? I am using python 3.2

**Update:**
The package is not located in the python folder. How does the python environment find it, so I can successfully import it by name.

Comment: Is `custom_module` available in your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: @mgilson hmm no please explain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sys.path` holds the Python search path. Before trying to `import` your modules and packages, set it to include your path:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'your_path_here')
import custom_module
```

More detail in the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path) and in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955024/how-is-the-python-module-search-path-determined-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: in this case if I make an installer package for my package I should be extracting it within the python directory or can I make the installer modify the sys.path with user selected directory?

Comment: sys.path modifications are only valid for your currently runnig script. If you want to permanently install your package into a given Python install, I recommend reading the [Official docs about the standard installation procedure](http://docs.python.org/py3k/install/index.html#standard-build-and-install). Generally installers call a `setup.py` inside your package and put your code into standard locations. You probably want to follow the standards so your module could be released on http://pypi.python.org. [Pypi docs](http://wiki.python.org/moin/CheeseShopTutorial)

Comment: In general, instead of telling Python to look somewhere non-standard, you should install your package to somewhere standard.

Answer (score 12):

There are two distinct concepts you are confusing: *packages* and *modules*.

A *module* is what you think it is: a Python script containing classes, variables, whatever. You import it by its filename, and can then access the variables in its namespace.

A *package* is a collection of modules which are grouped together inside a folder. If the folder contains a file called `__init__.py`, Python will allow you to import the entire folder as if it were a module. This will run the code in `__init__`, but will not necessarily import all of the modules in the folder. (This is a deliberate design choice: packages are often very large, and importing all of the modules could take a very long time.)

The only things which are exported (as `package.thing`) by default are the variables defined inside `__init__`. If you want `submodule` to be available as `package.submodule`, you need to import it inside `__init__`.

`__all__` is a related concept. In brief, it defines what is imported when you do `from package import *`, because it's not easy for Python to work out what that should be otherwise. You don't in general need it.

Comment: I understand all this (sorry it's a package not a module). However how do I make python find my package, because when I say import custom_module nothing happens. My package is not located in the python folder.