# Run Python .py File from any folder

Tags: python

I'm starting to create lots of python scripts.  These scripts are made to run on a number of files from the same folder the script is in.  I want to store this script in an organized folder, and be able to access the script from any folder I navigate to in the console.  How do I do this?

Thanks!

Edit: this is what I wanted to do, 
[How to import custom python package by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475678/how-to-import-custom-python-package-by-name)

Comment: python <path_to_your_script>\script.py

Comment: You want to access your script from anywhere or you want your script to access files from anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like this to access you scripts from anywhere:

```
>> python [path]\script.py
```

Answer (score -2):

This is OS dependent.  In windows it requires a .bat file in your path that invokes the python script from the folder where you're storing them.  In linux you can copy the scripts to /usr/bin.

Comment: So I can store all of my "in-house" python scripts in /usr/bin and python will know to look here first?

Comment: Not python - the shell will look there.  In linux you can mark a python script as executable - then the shell will find it there and execute it.  The first line of your python script should read:  #!/usr/bin/python - which tells the shell to use python when processing it.